# How to check if Entity is one of a ManyToMany relationship with Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a Profile and User Entity. Profiles can be related to users in one of three ways:

- primaryUser
- editUsers
- viewUsers

It's a basic permissions structure. What I need to do is get *all* Profiles by User, regardless of permissions granted. I think if I were using Doctrine 2.5.* I'd be ok as QueryBuilder has the 'member of' comparison added, but I'm on Symfony 2.7.* and unfortunately Doctrine only goes up to 2.4.* (some kind of stability issue it seems if you make the jump to Doctrine 2.5 with less than Symfony 3).

I'm unsure how to replicate the functionality though.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProfileRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAllByUser(User $user, $status = NULL)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $e  = $qb->expr();

        $qb->where($e->eq('p.primary_user', ':user'));
        // Some kind of comparison? a join?;
        $qb->setParameter('user', $user);
        $qb->setParameter('userId', $user->getId());

        if ($status) {
            $qb->andWhere($e->eq('p.status', ':status'));
            $qb->setParameter('status', $status);
        }

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions...

Using DQL:

```
SELECT p 
  FROM Profile p 
 WHERE p.primaryUser = :user 
    OR :user MEMBER OF p.editUsers 
    OR :user MEMBER OF p.viewUsers
```

Using QueryBuilder:

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("p");

$qb
    ->where("p.primaryUser = :user")
    ->orWhere(":user MEMBER OF p.editUsers")
    ->orWhere(":user MEMBER OF p.viewUsers")
    ->setParameter("user", $user)
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that MEMBER OF and the isMemberOf helper were added to Doctrine at different times.